# What is "move for"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In the entry of the word "move" in the Oxford dictionary (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/move_1?q=move", I came across the phrasal verb "move for" and I don't know what its meaning is. Could you please explain it for me?
The phrase is included in the following example:

> You can't move for books in her room.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's not a multi-word ['phrasal'] verb here. And OALD doesn't say it is (it lists phrasal verbs later). 'Move' retains its base meaning. _You can''t move_. // 'For' has various meanings as a preposition; [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) lumps **for** [2] _because of or as a result of something_: I'm feeling all the better for my holiday./ "How are you?" "Fine, and all the better for seeing you!" / ... I couldn't see for the tears in my eyes. / ... She couldn't talk for coughing (= she was coughing too much to talk). // [You can't see the wood for the trees].

Answer (score 1):

It means *due to the presence*. It's the same usage as the expression "Can't see the forest for the trees."

This usage is not current in my (American) dialect. If I was to use this, I would surely say "You can't move for all the books in her room," but I would be more likely to say something like, "You can't move, what with all the books in her room" or "You can't move because of the books in her room."

---

"Move for" has a different meaning, in parliamentary and legal procedure, relating to *make a motion*. "I move for Ms Lee's remarks to be stricken from the record." "I move for immediate dismissal of all the charges."

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Any references? I would say I move *to have* Ms Lee's remarks stricken from the record.